# react-router-dom possibility to have "oneof" params in one route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to have path like `/view/options` or `/view/3424` `/view/3424/options`. Is it possible with react-router-dom?

I want to use "options" like param but not as exact path. And I'm not sure if it will work like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/view/:options" component={...} />
  <Route exact path="/view/:id/:options" component={...} />
  <Route exact path="/view/:id" component={...} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to the [`<Switch>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) component for that. Instead of the normal behavior of displaying any route that matches, the `Switch` component will choose the first one that matches. Note that order matters.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/view/options" component={...} />
  <Route exact path="/view/:id/options" component={...} />
  <Route exact path="/view/:id" component={...} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: This will also work if you want to switch `options` to behave like a param. `exact` just means that you don't want to match that route if additional paths exist after what you've specified. In other words, for the first route `/view/options` will match but `/view/options/hello` will not match.

Comment: So in that case I got 3 the same components in one page. Yes them wrapped to ```Switch```. And ```exact={true}```

Answer (score -1):

Yes ,

```
<Route path="views/:id" component={yourComponent} />
<Route path="views/:id/options" component={yourComponent} />
```

After your go to the route if **views/:id** then you have **options component** in this route to go to the second route

Comment: No. See example above